# ggplot error Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

suppose the data frame is like this

```
df <- data.frame(age = c("20", "21", "22", "20", "21","22"), 
   female = c("female", "female", "female", "male", "male", "male"), 
   income =c("1000", "2000","3000", "1500", "2400", "5600"))
```

I want to get two lines from ggplot that show me the comparison of income between female and male.
I ran the following code:

```
 p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=age, y=income, group = female)) +
                         geom_line(color ="blue")
```

I got the following error:
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous

> Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the
>   dataProblems:female

Anyone has idea what's wrong?

Comment: Not able to reproduce the error in `ggplot2_1.0.1`

Comment: Maybe try color=female instead of group=female. And then just geom_line().

Comment: Your code ran perfectly.  Is there a way to show a plot other than in an answer?

Comment: I agree with @lawyeR ran your code and its runs perfectly. Cant reproduce the error in ggplot2_2.1.0

Comment: cat88 please delete this, it is just creating noise for anyone trying to resolve the cause of the same error message.